# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting reads and resources for skeptics
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3023).

Comment: could this template post be updated for the next iteration of ads? It still says that images must be 220 by 250, and they can now be 440 by 500 for retina. The number of comments on some other sites saying "this won't work" can be annoying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 20):

[image: Internet Archive WayBackMachine]

Comment: Copied from [this answer](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1045)

Answer (score 16):

[image: Facebook group dedicated to stopping the misinformation about vaccinations spread by the Australian Vaccination Network]

Comment: Reposted from last year.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Google Scholar Web Search: Stand on the shoulders of giants]

Comment: I came over here to comment that Google has changed their logo - next year we should update this. However, at the time of writing, Google Scholar hasn't been updated.

Comment: @Oddthinking Here's [an ad with the new Scholar logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CExBM.png), and tagline font changed to match it. Unlike [previously](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015#comment9699_3025), it's almost exactly the same: must we wait until next year?

Comment: @Oddthinking It has now updated. Could this post simply be edited or is that not allowed?

Comment: @Tim: It's a good question. I reckon posting an alternative is probably more proper. What do you think?

Comment: @Anko: That image has some antialiasing artifacts in the "Skip the hype" part. Does that appear at normal size?

Comment: @Oddthinking As it doesn't change the content, I can't see there being an issue. I'd think "would my opinion on voting change if that was the newer logo" and I doubt it would have significantly less votes, if any. I'd personally update it with this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcL4x.png. Unless you consider the new Google logo especially controversial?

Comment: @Tim: You persuaded me.

Answer (score 13):

[Current Skeptics Stack Exchange bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/skeptics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a magic image, shared by [Kyle Cronin](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521/64236), that automatically updates based on current unanswered bounties. (It is double-scale to look good on "retina" devices. It was in use last year, and I think it was awesome.

Answer (score 10):

[image: WOT is a free website reputation, rating and review tool that helps find trustworthy websites and protects against online scams, untrustworthy links, and unreliable web stores. Free add-on for Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari browsers.]

Comment: Reposted from last year.

Answer (score 10):

[image: A reference source for urban legends, folklore, myths, rumors, and misinformation.]

Comment: Reposted from last year, where it was [controversial](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2639/23).

Answer (score 9):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: Reposted from last year. Credit: [@Undo](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/a/366/49)

Answer (score 8):

[image: rbutr is a browser plugin that tells you when the webpage you are viewing has been disputed, rebutted or contradicted elsewhere on the internet.]

Comment: Reposted from last year.

Answer (score 8):

[image: curated community blog, discussion board, and archive of rationality materials]

Comment: ([As last year](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2939/7286).)

Answer (score 8):

[image: The Skeptics' Guide to the Universe]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Cochrane is a non-profit organization working to produce credible, accessible health information that is free from commercial sponsorship and other conflicts of interest.]

Comment: Reposted from last year.

Comment: I wish that 1) Cochrane reviews were made immediately available for free (and not after 12 months like in "green open access") 2) Cochrane was responding to my emails when asking for [API access](https://community.cochrane.org/editorial-and-publishing-policy-resource/open-access)…

Answer (score 4):

[image: Skeptic Action]

Comment: Reposted from last year.

Answer (score 0):

[image: HSM]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all we have at the moment, though myself or another HSM user may try to update the image.

Comment: I think you do need to update the image, because the "67 days in beta" and even the "view beta info" will not be correct.

Comment: @Oddthinking It's been finicky for a while. We now have a concept image featuring Archimedes.