# Incorporate today's SMBC into the site somehow

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion, skepticism

Today's [Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/giants) contains a proposed line from the keynote speech of a hypothesized "Skeptics Hall of Fame":

> If I have found more bullshit, it is because I have swum in the sewars of **giants**.

One of my first thoughts was that Skeptics.SE should contain a link to this somewhere, maybe the Tour, unless it's considered too flippant for a serious research site like this.

This is just a thought, do what you like with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate place would be a submission in the community promotion ads. Then we can vote on it, and it's automatically added if it passes the bar.

- Current year:
  [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4504/11643)

Comment: I guess we'd need to get permission from SMBC to copy the cartoon to imgur, right?

Comment: @Barmar That seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted an inquiry to them.